# How to concadenate list of list with reference variable in python

Tags: python

i have a List a

```
a = [["v1_0001.jpg","v1_00015.jpg","v1_0002.jpg"],["v2_0001.jpg","v2_0002.jpg","v2_00015.jpg"]]
```

i want to concatenate these list of list in one list and sort list by alphanumeric

While i am try to sort concatenation list

```
['v1_0001.jpg', 'v1_00015.jpg', 'v1_0002.jpg','v2_0001.jpg' 'v2_00015.jpg', 'v2_0002.jpg']
```

I got output like this

```
['v1_0001.jpg','v1_0002.jpg','v1_00015.jpg','v2_0001.jpg','v2_00015.jpg' 'v2_0002.jpg]
```

How to resolve this in python

Comment: Is something wrong with my answer?

Comment: You can build a dictionary like that. But that's a separate question and should be posted separately...

Comment: If this solution is good please "accept" as customary

Comment: @ShlomiF Hello how i do the same process for alpha numeric like .jpg files

Comment: i want to do concatenation and sorting for this a = ["v1_0001.jpg","v1_0002.jpg","v1_0003.jpg","v1_0004.jpg","v1_00015.jpg"]
b = ["v2_0001.jpg","v2_0002.jpg","v2_0003.jpg","v2_0004.jpg","v2_00015.jpg"]

Comment: You're asking about concatenating? Because string-data works exactly the same. Sorting is a completely different matter and I don't understand what the problem is...

Comment: @ShlomiF some list i given above comment if is sort that list 00015.jpg comes 2nd elemnt in  the list thats why am asking

Comment: I answered on your new question. Please accept "correct" answers on both of your posts.

Answer (score 0):

Use `chain` from `itertools`, as so -

```
from itertools import chain

a = [[0, 15, 30, 45, 75, 105],[0, 15, 30, 45, 75, 105]]
b = list(chain(*a))
print(b)
# [0, 15, 30, 45, 75, 105,0, 15, 30, 45, 75, 105]
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. `a` can contain a list of lists containing any object.

Answer (score -1):

Here is one way. You can do it with recursion

```
solution :
```

```
import itertools
a = [[0, 15, 30, 45, 75, 105],[0, 15, 30, 45, 75, 105]]
print(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(a)))
```

Comment: i think you give a list but my question is list of list Like  'a = [[0, 15, 30, 45, 75, 105],[0, 15, 30, 45, 75, 105]]'

Comment: @HarryMc, I give a list of list as an argument

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this is not the best to use in big lists but for understanding the logic might be good:

```
>>> a = [[0, 15, 30, 45, 75, 105],[0, 15, 30, 45, 75, 105]]
>>> b = []  # Creates an empty list
>>> for list_inside_a in a:  # For every list in a
...     b+= list_inside_a  # Concatenates n-th list with b
...
>>> b
[0, 15, 30, 45, 75, 105, 0, 15, 30, 45, 75, 105]
```